# How to launch an app in memory on linux system

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

I read the encrypted file, decrypt it in a buffer. how could I run the decrypted code?
where should I jump to? in DOS, I know, jump to the buffer offset 0x100, that's the code entry point. how about in linux?

thank you
Xian

Comment: What format is the file?  Does it need locating to run where you loaded it?  You will need to set execute permission on the buffer.

Comment: the file is generated by gcc. like gcc abc.c -o abc

Answer (score 0):

Try using tail -c (output last K bytes).

Full answer:

First convert from hex to dec (remove the "0x" before converting)

Then, find your input file size. Deduct 0x100

```
hex="100"
# convert hex to dec
dec=$(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; ${hex}" | bc)
# input_file size in bytes
file_size=$(stat --printf="%s" input_file)
truncated_file_size=$(($file_size - $dec))
tail -c $truncated_file_size input_file > new_file
```

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. that this script does?